# How to handle optional parameter for Class.new

Tags: ruby

I create a dynamic class using the `Class.new` method. But sometimes I call the method with a parameter to create an inherited class - sometimes without.

Option 1:

```
newclass = Class.new do
  ...
end
```

Option 2:

```
newClass = Class.new(p) do
  ...
end
```

The body of the new class is identical. But I cannot call `Class.new(p)` with undefined `p`. So I have to create an if statement and then either call `Class.new` with parameter or without which means I have the duplicate the code for creating the class which is not ideal since every change in my code I have to make twice. Any way how I can get around this?

Comment: JFYI, this question has nothing to do with rails. Just ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Only the OP's name sounds Railish.

Comment: Used to be tagged rails...tag got removed already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just abstract the `Class.new` call and leave the block in one place. Something like this:

```
def create_me_a_class(superklass = Object, &block)
  Class.new(superklass, &block)
end

newclass = create_me_a_class(p) do
  def my_method
    # whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: I would suggest to set `possible_superclass = Object` by default, since w/o params Class.new creates a class inherited from `Object` class. So, we can get rid of `if` statement.

Comment: @nattfodd: agreed. Confident code, it's called. :) Although there is a tiny chance of default superclass change when you upgrade ruby. Not sure if it's worth worrying about.

Comment: Hi, Perfect! If I assign possible_superclass = Object it does the job! I can call the Class.New with its parent - either Object or another class and it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MichaelH.: it's `Class.new` btw, not `Class.New`. This is very important.

Comment: Perhaps you have also an idea how to resolve a second issue. This new class includes       include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

Comment: Perhaps you have also an idea how to resolve a second issue. This new class includes Mongoid::Document and Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic. Since it is a dynamic class for a mongdb model.

Within my class definition I do:

          entity.relationships.each do |relationship|
              if relationship.typ =='Belongs To'
                  e = Entity.find(relationship.relationship_id)
                  belongs_to e.name.downcase
                  default_scope { includes(e.name.downcase)}
            end
      end

But I get some weird errors with this when creating a new record.

Comment: @MichaelH. perhaps I would [have an idea] if code blocks in comments were readable.

Comment: Sergio, I will edit my original question so it will be readable.

Comment: Sergio, instead of changing this posting, can you go to my other posting? I already raised this quesion with the title: 'rails mongoid dynamc model fails'